# Any alternatives to this awk script to soothen subversion pain?

Tags: linux, svn, awk

On my development server, I run *svn updates* to deploy bug fixes or changes to the webapp's code. Normally I run:

```
svn stat --show-updates
```

and then selectively chose which files to update; appending the selected files to the end of a *svn update* command.

I miss GIT's command line interface and as a concession, I just want to improve the speed of performing the updates (but limited to files which do not have conflicts).

e.g. In the following example, I only want to update *Country.properties*

```
       *     5602   conf/country/Country.properties
M            5331   conf/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
M      *     5451   conf/scripts/changes.rb
```

This is the awk snippet that does the trick for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/*/ { if( NF == 3 ) { system( "svn up " $3 ); } }
```

My question: Is there an extension to subversion that will act like GIT's *git add -i* command ? Or is it pretty normal for people to do what I'm doing ?

Comment: How is `git add -i` related to choosing which files you want to update from the central repository?

Comment: You are correct of course. git add -i allows you decide which files to update/add into the repo.

Comment: This sounds weird; just because files in the repo aren't conflicting with yours, that doesn't mean they're not *dependent* on files that are. In the general case, I don't think SVN expects you to "cherry-pick" parts of revisions like that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want an interactive UI (a la `git add -i`) which can be used to select which files in your working copy to update from the central repository.  If that's the case, then I have to agree with unwind's comment that one shouldn't generally be doing partial tree updates (regardless of which VCS is being used).  Accordingly, I don't think I've ever seen an SVN UI that makes it easy to do partial updates, let alone partial updates that use the set of remotely changed files as a starting base.